# Sort the first N elements of a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting

I would like to sort the first N elements of a vector that has more elements. 
For example:

```
A = [3 2 5 1 8 9 2 1 9];
```

If `N = 5`, the output should be:

```
B = [1 2 3 5 8 9 2 1 9];
```

I would also like to have a vector of indices `v`, so that `B = A(v)`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[B, v] = sort(A(1:N));
B = [B, A(N+1:end)];    % sorted vector
v = [v, N+1:numel(A)];  % index vector
```

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to have also a vector of indices, so that I could do `B = A(vector_of_indices)`.

Comment: @baister I've improved my answer